# jQuery toggleClass, проверка внутри функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Внутри события toggleClass, есть функция которая возвращает нужный класс в зависимости от результата проверки условия:

```
$(".player").toggleClass(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass("play") ? $(this).removeClass("play").addClass("stop") : $(this).removeClass("stop").addClass("play");
});
```

В это самую функцию, мне надо добавить ещё одно действие, применяемое к другому селектору **$("audio")[0].muted=true**

Я пытался сделать так, вернуть ещё одну проверку, но это плохая идея:

```
$(".player").toggleClass(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass("play") ? $(this).removeClass("play").addClass("stop") : $(this).removeClass("stop").addClass("play");
    return $(this).hasClass("play") ? $("audio")[0].muted=true : $("audio")[0].muted=false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил это так:

```
if($(this).hasClass("play")) {
    a = $(this).removeClass("play").addClass("stop");
    b = $("audio")[0].muted=true;
    return [a, b];
} else {
    a = $(this).removeClass("stop").addClass("play");
    b = $("audio")[0].muted=false;
    return [a, b];
}
```